# Invalid Header when including customer provided key to upload file to Azure Blob

Tags: encryption, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I'm following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-customer-provided-key) to include customer provided key when uploading file to Azure Blob. My code is using string key instead of byte[]. I have tried different format of key such as:

1. Plain text string: "my key"
2. Base 64 AES 256 encrypted key generated from this [link](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption)

When I upload file using above customer provided key, it throws "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correnct format". I'm suspecting it is due to the encryption key is not included in the header.

Is my key generated in a correct approach? Or is there any configuration I have missed out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way to generate base 64 encrypted key when you add key as string.

```
string base64Encoded = "YmFzZTY0IGVuY29kZWQgc3RyaW5n";
byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/encryption-customer-provided-keys).